# A question on star $\sigma$-compact spaces

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $X$ is said to be star $\sigma$-compact if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a $\sigma$-compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

Let $X$  have countable extent and is locally compact. Then must $X^2$ be star $\sigma$-compact?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is $\omega_1^2$ star $\sigma$-compact?

Comment: @Alex: $\omega_1^2$ is even star-countable; it follows easily from the pressing-down lemma.