# Questions on the product of the space which has countable extent

Tags: general-topology

This question can be seen the continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381016/let-x-has-countable-extent-does-x2-have-countable-extent) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376843/a-question-on-star-sigma-compact-spaces?rq=1).

First, let us recall some relevant definitions.

> **Definition 1:** A space $X$ has countable extent if every uncountable subset of $X$ has an accumulation point in $X$.
>
> **Definition 2:** A topological space $X$ is said to be star countable if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a countable subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.
>
> **Definition 3:** A topological space $X$ is said to be star $\sigma$-compact if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a $\sigma$-compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

**Note that countable extent implies star countable implies star $\sigma$-compact.**

I'm struggling with this question:

> **Question 4: Let $X$ have countable extent and $X$ be locally compact and locally metrizable. Does $X^2$ have countable extent? Is $X^2$ star countable? Is $X^2$ star $\sigma$-compact?**

Thanks for your help.